# Haskell code to verify credit number

Tags: beginner, haskell, checksum

I am new to Haskell, and wrote a script to verify credit number.
I did some tests, the script worked, but can it be improved further?

```
isCreditCardNumber :: String -> Bool
isCreditCardNumber number =
    0 == creditCardReminder ( creditCardDouble ( blowupCreditCardNumber ( reverse number)))

blowupCreditCardNumber :: String -> [(Int,Char)]
blowupCreditCardNumber creditCardNumber = zip [1..] creditCardNumber

creditCardDouble :: [(Int,Char)] -> [Int]
creditCardDouble [] = []
creditCardDouble ((index,digit):rest)
    | even index = (numberDoubleToList ((*2) $ digitToInt digit)) ++ creditCardDouble rest
    | otherwise = digitToInt digit : creditCardDouble rest

numberDoubleToList:: Int -> [Int]
numberDoubleToList number
    | number > 9 = map digitToInt (show number)
    | otherwise  = [number]

creditCardReminder :: [Int] -> Int
creditCardReminder xs = sum xs `mod` 10
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can eta-reduce `blowupCreditCardNumber`:

```
blowupCreditCardNumber = zip [1..]
```

Using composition, you can also make isCreditCardNumber pointfree:

```
isCreditCardNumber = (==0) . creditCardReminder . creditCardDouble . blowupCreditCardNumber . reverse
```

You don't need to optimize `numberDoubleToList` by special-casing the one-digit case.

```
numberDoubleToList = map digitToInt . show
```

The explicit recursion in `creditCardDouble` can be averted by using library functions that specialize in particular recursive patterns:

```
creditCardDouble = concatMap foo where
  foo (index, digit) | even index = numberDoubleToList $ (*2) $ digitToInt digit
                     | otherwise = [digitToInt digit]
```

`foo`'s name makes `foo` look like a crutch, and that is good, because it is one.

I would inline definitions that are only used once and do not deserve to be in a library:

```
isCreditCardNumber = (==0) . (`mod` 10) . sum . concatMap foo . zip [1..] . reverse where
  foo (index, digit) | even index = map digitToInt $ show $ (*2) $ digitToInt digit
                     | otherwise = [digitToInt digit]
```

`digitToInt digit` is used in both cases of foo, and so can be factored out:

```
isCreditCardNumber = (==0) . (`mod` 10) . sum . concatMap foo . zip [1..] . reverse where
  foo (index, digit) = bar index $ digitToInt digit
  bar index | even index = map digitToInt . show  . (*2)
            | otherwise = pure
```

In fact, we don't need to generate the index and pass it to `foo` if all we do with it is put it into `bar` later:

```
isCreditCardNumber = (==0) . (`mod` 10) . sum . concatMap foo . zip (cycle [pure, map digitToInt . show . (*2)]) . reverse where
  foo (doubler, digit) = doubler $ digitToInt digit
```

`foo` is almost trivial, lets get rid of it entirely:

```
isCreditCardNumber = (==0) . (`mod` 10) . sum . concat . zipWith ($) (cycle [pure, map digitToInt . show . (*2)]) . map digitToInt . reverse
```

`map digitToInt . show` is `pure` on single digits, so we can factor it out of that list and then even factor out the `(*)`:

```
isCreditCardNumber = (==0) . (`mod` 10) . sum . concatMap (map digitToInt . show) . zipWith (*) (cycle [1, 2]) . map digitToInt . reverse
```

Note that if you know the parity of the length of the credit card number, you can get rid of the `reverse`.

Comment: wow, mate, this is so amazing!!! looks like I have a long way to learn Haskell.

Comment: hi mate, looks like "concatMap (digitToInt . show)" has  change to concatMap ((\y -> map digitToInt y) . show)

Comment: Ah, of course. `concatMap (map digitToInt . show)`, that is. (Or, if you want, `map digitToInt . concatMap show`, but that might give a little bit of a different intuition about what the code does?) Let me edit in that missing `map` in the last code block.